# Как отличить паттерн mediator?

Tags: javascript, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Я написал два простейших примера паттерна mediator. Помогите пожалуйста определить оба ли они являются равноправными и соответственно могут называться медиаторами или нет.

Если кратко, то есть объекты player и canvas. Они общаются через объект game, который является медиатором.

Кода не очень мало, но отличаются они только парой строк.

В первом я передаю canvas из game в player так:

```
this.player = new Player({
.......
  canvas: this.canvas
});
```

И использую в player так:

```
constructor(initObj) {
  .....
  this.canvas = initObj.canvas;
}
```

Во втором примере передаю canvas из game в player так:

```
this.player = new Player({
.......
  game: this.game
});
```

И использую в player так:

```
constructor(initObj) {
  .....
  this.game = initObj.game;
}

......
...this.game.canvas.width....
```

Вот [первый](https://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/ks0sbb5b/) пример. Вот [второй](https://jsfiddle.net/gb25zva4/2/) пример.

Могут ли в будущем возникнуть проблемы из-за такого различия в написании?